# Does one use ListAdapters with Android Room?

Tags: android, android-room

In an older app, I used straight SqlLite, built list adapters, had and XML file for the activity and another one for each item.... is there a new "magic" way to do this with Room? Room I have up and running, it can create the tables and stick data in, fine. But what is(are) the proper way(s) to show the data? Is it LiveData or nothing?

For this app, we're talking about displaying small (under 100) items in a scrolling view. Each one is only showing two items of text, you'll tap and edit one of the fields, save it, and done.

A recipe list of the actual files/classes I'll need to create would be super. I've seen plenty of code snippets but there's very little clarity on where those pieces live, and the XML layout files which seem like they must exist never get mentioned.

Comment: AFAIK You can query room and populate a list adapter the same way you probably got your data before. You just need to get a list of objects to feed to your adapter. Room supports that without LiveData. I was looking for an example, but couldnt find a simple one.

Comment: I couldn't find simple examples either. ;) I could also use Room in one part of the app and go straight SQLite in the UI but that is of course horrible.

Comment: There is now [an example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) in google's documentation